# Odin 6.0 Beta: Cant update kernel

Tags: kernel

Been trying out the 6.0 early release, but cant seem to update the kernel which is needed for my laptop. The early release has 5.4 and I need 5.8 (AMD 4500U).

I *think* I am doing the same as I did with the PopOS install I have it dual booted with, but nothing seems to happen. When I reboot `uname -r` gives the same 5.4 kernel, and I cant see anything in grub either.

I have tried with various kernels from the ubuntu kernel download page, and installed with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` from the folder I stored the files in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/rshetye/kmp-downloader to download rs-kmpd-python3.py for python3-based download and install of mainline kernels.

Comment: So it there an issue with my original method?

Comment: You can use the utility I linked to, and see what it does . From there on, you can replicate the same manually using your steps. I cannot point to what you are or might be or might not be doing wrong, because you have not listed every step you're executing.